# Laravel get model from ID with belongtoMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I'm building an application using Laravel 4 but have some problems with the pivot tables.

there are 3 tables Categories , Products , products_categories (pivot)

Category model

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'products_categories');

}
```

Products Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'products_categories');
}
```

`products_categories` table has `product_id` and `category_id` columns.

What I want is take all products in this category and list them in views

```
$category = Category::where('id' , '=' , '7')->first();

    foreach($category->product as $product){

        echo $product->id;
    }
```

I can see product ids related with particular category but when I want to use it to get all product itself like:

```
    $category = Category::where('id' , '=' , '7')->first();

    foreach($category->product as $product){

        $product = Product::where('id' , '=' , $product->id )->get();
    }

    return View::make('index')->with('product',$product);
```

it doesn't work :( with this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

I tried this

```
$category = Category::where('id' , '=' , '7')->first();

    $product = array();

    foreach($category->product as $product){

        $product[] = Product::where('id' , '=' , $product->id )->get();

    }

    return View::make('index')->with('product',$product);
```

this time it throws this error

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute()

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you're trying to reuse your iterator variable from the foreach loop. This is leading to your unexpected results.

```
foreach($category->product as $product) {
                              ^^^^^^^^
    $product = Product::where('id' , '=' , $product->id )->get();
    ^^^^^^^^
}
```

However, there is no need to do any of that. `$category->product` is already a Collection of the Eloquent Product models. There is no need to try and retrieve the individual products again; you already have them.

If you're trying to pass this Collection to the view, you could just do:

```
return View::make('index')->with('product', $category->product);
```

Also, as a side note, if you're trying to find a record by the id, you can use the `find()` method:

```
$category = Category::find(7);
```